# Sum $\lim_{x\to -\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The value of $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ is

a.) $-\infty$

b.) $\infty$

c.) $0$

d.) $e^{-1}$

I tried expanding the series but it got me nowhere. Then i thought the expanded sequence is a part of e^x but it goes to infinity and in question it is only up to 1000.

Comment: This is only a finite sum, so you can move the limit inside the summation with no problems.

Comment: If the limit is to minus infinity, perhaps you can try factoring out $x^{1000}$

Comment: Hint: One of the terms in the sum dominates the others when $|x|$ is very large.

Comment: @RobertIsrael i guess you are talking about the $x^{1000}$ term, it will be the largest if we put the $-\infty$, but how can we say that this will be greater than any other term, i mean all terms are generating either  $-\infty$ or  $\infty$.

Comment: @FedePoncio Thank You very much for your help i think i got the answer. By taking out the $x^{1000}$ all other terms will become $0$ except the last term. how silly of me i didn't see the obvious.

Comment: @Broly-29 glad to have helped!